# Is it possible or desirable to run MySQL without any MyISAM tables?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

We would like to avoid using MyISAM tables because they don't support transactions.  However, I've noticed that many internal tables in MySQL use MyISAM.  I can get a list like this:

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where engine = 'MyISAM';
```

Is it possible to set up MySQL in a way where none of its tables will use MyISAM?  Can MySQL work properly in this way?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html indicates it's optional

Comment: Did you read my question?

Comment: Of course I read your question.  If you are declaring the engine to be `MyISAM` then technically that table isn't consiered to be an internal table.  If you want an internal table you want to declare the engine as `memory`  *Please remember the most important rule is to be nice to everyone*.  You can also use the `InnoDB` engine type, although that also, wouldn't be considered an internal table.

Comment: Run the query in my question and see what you find.  Not all internal tables use the "memory" engine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is it possible and desirable to run MySQL without any MyISAM tables.

Since I started using MySQL (V5.5 now 5.6) with all InnoDB type, I have found no issues.

Comment: Did you read my question?  I'm talking about internal MySQL tables.  I'd like to know how to even set it up this way.

Comment: then you may try experimenting changing each MyISAM table that you see to any engine you want. the syntax is `ALTER TABLE <table_name> ENGINE=<engine_type>;` so will find your answer.